# wxPython: How to fix the size of one part of a grid sizer

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer

What I want to do is create 3 column that will expand as the window expands.  But I want to put limits on it so the different columns expand to different maximum amounts.

What I have done here is used wxGlade to create a frame w/ a grid sizer that has 1 row and three columns.  I want Part1 to have a fixed width of 'A', Part2 to have a fixed width of 'B' and Part3 to be able to expand as normal.

How do I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Tue May 24 11:35:21 2011

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade



class MyFrame1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer_10_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panel_1, -1, "Part2")
        self.sizer_11_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panel_1, -1, "Part3")
        self.sizer_9_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.panel_1, -1, "Part1")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_2")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame1.__do_layout
        sizer_8 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_4 = wx.GridSizer(1, 3, 0, 0)
        sizer_11 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_11_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_10 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_10_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_9 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_9_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        grid_sizer_4.Add(sizer_9, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_4.Add(sizer_10, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_4.Add(sizer_11, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(grid_sizer_4)
        sizer_8.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_8)
        sizer_8.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_2 = MyFrame1(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_2)
    frame_2.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: wxGlade's naming conventions make me ill.  `self.sizer_11_staticbox`?  In large projects it becomes nearly impossible to tell what's even going on in some of the layout functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a [GridSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxgridsizer.html#wxgridsizer) I'd probably suggest you take a look at [GridBagSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxgridbagsizer.html#wxgridbagsizer) instead.

Once you decide if that'll be usable, then you probably need to look into the `sizer.AddGrowableRow(row)` and `sizer.AddGrowableCol(col)` methods.  They allow you to indicate columns or rows in the grid that expand.  They don't use use proportions like you're familiar with from the BoxSizers (so if two columns grow they both grow at the same rate) but you can set some that expand and others that don't.

Indexes are zero based, so by your description I'd guess something like `gridbagsizer_4.AddGrowableCol(2)`, but like my comment says, wxGlade's naming conventions make me ill and it's hard to tell for certain, and those methods won't be available on the GridSizer.

For any interested parties, there's a post covering my form building and form dialog classes available here: [Form Builder](http://code.ghostdev.com/posts/wxpython-form-builder). It was easier to post it on my site where I could include attachments than to try to paste it all here.

Comment: Ill check that out, never heard of GridBagSizer.... and your correct, I don't like wxGlades naming conventions - but as a tool to quickly mock up a GUI I like it better than anything else, meaning BoaConstructor.

Comment: For a quick tool it's ok, but if you need to customize later it becomes a headache. I actually ended up rolling my own form generator and form dialog classes that take in a structured object and parse it into a full form. It automates sizer creation and placement, which is a huge plus in my book. I'd be willing to shoot you a copy if you're interested. Also, you may take a look at XRCed - it's similar to wxGlade, but uses an XML Structure that's not terrible to work with.

Comment: Im trying XRCed now, but can't seem to get GridBagSizer to work correctly.  Could you mock up an example of what my problem from above should look like?  I can create the GridBagSizer, but when I attempt to add a static sizer to it it errors out.  Also have been trying FlexGridSizer, but so far I have not been able to correctly set min/max sizes.

Comment: Can a sizer have a min size?  As a test I created a wxStaticBox and was able to force that to a min size.  I then created a wxStaticBoxSizer and used the same option and using wxFixed_MINSIZE had no effect

Comment: As I understand it, the sizer is supposed to determine its own min size.  So I guess what I need to do is to be able to define the max size of a single column.  GridBag and FlexGrid 'should' be able to do this by setting a specific columns to grow and others to be static in size.  But so far I have not been able to get it to fully work

Comment: @Fenikso, @ccwhite1 - I've update my response with a link to the Form Builder I'm currently using in our projects.  Fair warning - when I say home-grown I mean "may not conform to others' design expectations".  It does quite well in our application and has simplified the process for creating dialogs / interfaces dramatically.

Comment: Im very disapointed in XRCed.  I got a layout I liked and when I try to save the file it provides an 'invalid mode' error :(.  Posted to the mailing list but it looks like there has been no activity on this since 2009

Comment: @ccwhite1 - That's unfortunate. I tested it briefly, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for either.

Comment: To solve my problems I ended up using the Flex Grid Sizer.  It was very complex as I had to nest different FlexGridSizers in such a way as to get the result I wanted.  Not the exact answer given here, but it is close enough and this answer put me onto the solution I eventually used